# Drawing form singular multivariate truncated normal

Tags: gaussian

Is there any algorithm for generating draws from a multivariate truncated normal with singular covariance matrix?

Comment: Question needs add at which platform is the question for.

Comment: Thank you Sharman for the answer. There is no question about platform (all platform is fine for me) , I am only interested if there exists such algorithms and where I can find the underline theory.